# MOSFET gate driver scheme

Tags: mosfet, gate-driving

There are many common gate driving circuits, but I think none of them solves my current issue. In my device, I need to slow down the MOSFET a little bit to remove ringing on the switching node, but doing so with a resistor makes Miller capacitance dominant over the gate driver - and then it's a mess.

I am thinking about decoupling the slope forming circuit from the gate. I am going to build something like maybe an RC circuit for the slope and an emitter follower amplifier on the gate.

I have certain concerns about actually slowing down the MOSFET turn on this way - it's not the slope itself, right? It's the current that charges the gate above the threshold. It might happen that the amplifier will simply open the MOSFET up quickly once the threshold is reached.

So the questions are:

- Is this a valid way to drive a gate?
- What other ways are there to reliably slow down the MOSFET turn on without getting interference through Miller capacitance?
- Can I accomplish all that while keeping the timing of the turn on as accurate as possible to allow multiple MOSFETs to simultaneously turn on?

[image]

Comment: You can add a capacitor across the gate and the source to slow down the turn-on. If you end up with a too large capacitance then you can place a smaller one across the gate and drain instead (it'll be multiplied by the transconductance and reflect to gate-source). For turning on multiple MOSFETs at the same time, it's not possible because of practical differences coming from manufacturing. Even if you force one to track another for turn-on, thresholds and Q-t behaviours will be different. So the thing depends more on the delay that is acceptable for you.

Comment: Thank you. A simultaneous turn on of course is not possible, but i do want short and predictable events.

Comment: Is your problem related to drain dV/dt or dI/dt? If so, how about some R+C impedance across D-G, or R||L (often a ferrite bead) in series with the source?

Comment: @TimWilliams initial issue was with dV/dt. Capacitor in parallel with the gate is one option, I'll try to find something that work.

Comment: Why is Miller capacitance "a mess"? gate resistance together with Cgd is doing just what are you saying -- controlled dV/dt at the drain. Can you be more specific why simple gate resistance (eventually with additional discrete Cgd) is not what you want?

Comment: Martin yes, but it is not the only thing happening. When the switching node rings, the ringing gets to the gate as it comes at fairly high frequency, and then several things happen. Sometimes Mosfet goes off for a short while, other times the driver gets, destroyed (still not quite sure how).